# How to selectively deactivate Rails I18n translation_missing spans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

In my Rails 5.2 app, almost all my UI, except the Admin area, is internationalized using t(). The "translation missing" spans often break the layout, but I figure that's a price worth paying in order to know when I may have misspelled a key or not committed a file or something. There is one place where the spans really don't work however, and that is when it comes to the self-described roles people have in my Groups. The roles can be pre-defined strings that are part of my en.yml, like "coordinator", "treasurer" and so on, but they can also be write-ins, like "minister of awesome". So doing `t("groups.roles." + role)` doesn't work because the "translation missing" span messes up the layout. This wasn't a problem in previous version of Rails because the "translation missing" spans were automatically disabled for the production environment and only the last part of the key was displayed, i.e. exactly the functionality I want here. In Rails 5.2 the spans also show up in production and this is a problem, at least for this part.

The functionality I'd really want, which used to be standard, is:

1. If the translation exists, display it.
2. If the translation doesn't exist, display the English string from en.yml  (English is defined as a fallback language)
3. If the English doesn't exist either, display the final part of the key. With "translation missing" spans in development, without them in production.

Answer (score 1):

I browsed all the answers on here about how to disable these error messages in production and the suggested solutions seem geared at Rails 4 or don't work. Or they have the side effect of deactivating fallback translations, which is an unacceptable trade-off for me because I need English fallbacks for much of my app. Overwriting or extending the [TranslationHelper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb) seems like a momentous task, especially since I'd only want the spans removed in production (like it used to work). So for my case and for now, I've decided against doing a complete override and I only changed the helper in the one place where I expect to have missing translations that are not a problem:

```
def human_role(role)
  str = t("groups.roles." + role)
  if str.include?("translation missing")
    role
  else 
    str
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:default`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#defaults) option like this:

```
t("groups.roles.#{role}", default: role)
```

And if you want to have `"translation missing"` in development, without them in production (it's ugly a little):

```
t("groups.roles.#{role}", default: Rails.env.development? ? "#{role} translation missing" : role)
```

Comment: I tried that, but default overrides the fallback to English. I need it to fallback to English first and then use the key as a second fallback. ("translation missing" is never necessary for roles, only for the rest)